# Resolving or injecting dependency in global.asax using autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I need to execute some one-time code on start of my application in the global.asax. I've already got autofac up and running with numerous registrations but the problem is that I can't figure out how to resolve or inject a dependency into *SecurityConfig.RegisterActivities()* that's inside my global.asax.

I tried manually resolving the dependency myself in global.asax using the autofac container but it threw the exception "**No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.**"

How do I get this dependency into that class?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        DependencyRegistrar dr = new DependencyRegistrar();
        dr.Register(builder);

        new SecurityConfig().RegisterActivities(); // this needs injecting into or resolving of IServiceManager instance
}

public class DependencyRegistrar
{
    public virtual IContainer Register(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceManager>().As<IServiceManager>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SecurityConfig>().AsSelf().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerDependency();
    }
}

public class SecurityConfig
{
    public void RegisterActivities()
    {
        ServiceManager.DoSomething();
    }

    public IServiceManager ServiceManager { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you resolve the `SecurityConfig` from the container? Why doesn't this `container.Resolve<SecurityConfig>().RegisterActivities();` work?

Comment: That throws the error: **No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.**

Comment: In other words, there is a registration that needs a web request, but you don't run in the context of a web request. Try wrapping the operation in a lifetime scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allowed me to resolve my dependencies finally.

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"))
{
    scope.Resolve<SecurityConfig>().RegisterActivities();
}
```

Comment: This is actually creating a separate scope and disposing of it. Have a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173210/get-same-instance-of-a-component-registered-with-autofac-as-instanceperlifetimes)